How To Configure An Azure Data Factory Service And Azure Managed SQL Instance To Work On The Same Network As An On Prem SQL Host
I have an On Prem SQL host behind the company network.
I also have an ADF configuration that is currently used for ETL orchestration involving that particular host.
I want to set up an Azure SQL Managed Instance in the same Resource Group as my ADF service and moved data from that On Prem host to the Azure SQL Instance.
I am currently encountering all sorts of connectivity issues.  I cannot even connect to the Managed Instance in SSMS on or off the network.
My networking team claimed they set up a VNET to allow open communication but that doesn't appear to be working.
Hail mary-ing here, but do any of yall have insights into this?  I am a data tech focused guy so networking isn't my strong suit.  Thanks in advance!


I cannot even connect to the Managed Instance in SSMS on or off the network.

If you don't enable it, you won't be able to connect through SSMS.  You should enable Public endpoint in managed instance networking tab as shown below:

This option requires port 3342 to be open for inbound traffic. You will need to configure NSG rule for this port separately. So, create inbound rule for port 3342 by following this MS document. After creatin it use public endpoint which is mentioned above image to connect managed instance from SSMS with credentials as shown below:

It will connect to SSMS successfully as shown below:

You will be able to create linked service with same details of managed instance successfully as shown below:

You can use above linked service to transfer data from on-premises to Azure SQL managed instance.

Thank you for the feedback!  This is what the networking team is trying to avoid, they dont want public endpoints enable on Azure SQL Instances at all.  Trying to assist them with a work around.

Try with private endpoint for managed SQL instance in adf.

@NaveenSharma this does not resolve the issue I am having.

Did you try with private endpoint for managed SQL instance in adf?
